# pass build_ext options to pip install

Tags: python, build, installation, pip

Is there some way to pass `build_ext` options to pip install to alter how an extension included in a package is compiled? (Yes, I know that one can download the source and build/install with a custom `setup.cfg`, but I'm curious whether it is possible to pass options that can be specified in `setup.cfg` directly through pip.)

Answer (score 19):

It's possible using `pip --global-option=build_ext`.

For example this is `requirements.txt` for Pillow with PNG and JPEG support and no other external libraries:

```
pillow \
        --global-option="build_ext" \
        --global-option="--enable-zlib" \
        --global-option="--enable-jpeg" \
        --global-option="--disable-tiff" \
        --global-option="--disable-freetype" \
        --global-option="--disable-tcl" \
        --global-option="--disable-tk" \ 
        --global-option="--disable-lcms" \
        --global-option="--disable-webp" \
        --global-option="--disable-webpmux" \
        --global-option="--disable-jpeg2000"
```

This is really an abuse of `pip --global-option`, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942120/15862), as `build_ext` is a pip command and not really a global pip option. But this would make pip to execute two commands — first `build_ext` and then `install` — like this:

```
pip \
    build_ext \
        --enable-zlib --enable-jpeg \
        --disable-tiff --disable-freetype --disable-tcl --disable-tk \
        --disable-lcms --disable-webp --disable-webpmux --disable-jpeg2000 \
    install pillow
```

Comment: Excellent. Works like charm.

Comment: pip build_ext doesn't work for me at this time.

Answer (score 13):

You can create `.pydistutils.cfg` file in your home directory and override build options like you could do with custom `setup.cfg`, but without need to unpack package first.

So, for example, you can write something like this to alter include & lib search path:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/usr/local/include
library_dirs=/usr/local/lib64
rpath=/usr/local/lib64
```

Comment: Funny that I've googled up my own answer after completely forgetting I once knew this.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for such option in `pip` and found none (searched the [source](https://github.com/pypa/pip) too).

I don't think there is no such option in [easy_install/setuptools](http://grokbase.com/t/python/distutils-sig/068837rg3g/distutils-passing-build-ext-arguments-to-easy-install) too.

The only solution I see is an old-school way:

`download / unpack / setup.py build_ext [options] / setup.py install`.